# Is $\log(\sqrt{n}) = O(\log(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm studying asymptotic analysis and I have a doubt about this comparison.

So, is $\log(\sqrt{n})$ thus $\log(n^{1/2}) = O(\log(n))$?

Or are they asymptotically equivalent?

Comment: $\log \sqrt n = \dfrac12 \log n = \mathcal O \left( \log n \right)$, because multiplying by a constant does not change the asymptotic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\log\sqrt n=\frac12\log n$, so we have $\log\sqrt n\leq C\log n$ with $C=\frac12$, and so $\log\sqrt n=O(\log n)$.